# Explanation of this new() statement

Tags: c++

I am reviewing a section of C++ code an I came accross this statement block:

```
static void Vector3DefaultConstructor(Vector3 *self)
{    
    new(self) Vector3();    
}
```

I have not come accross the new operator being used in this way before. Can someone explain why new is being called in this way?

Comment: As the answers say, it's placement-new. The *practical* reason for writing this might be to provide a C-compatible interface to a C++ library, although other uses (like my std::vector example) are a bit more conventional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called "placement `new`". By default, it does not allocate memory but instead constructs the object at the given location (here, `self`). It can, however, be overloaded for a class.

See the [FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html#faq-11.10) for more info.

The correct way to destroy an object constructed using placement `new` is by calling the destructor directly:

```
obj->~Vector3();
```

Comment: Well, there could also be an overload for `Vector3*` specifically.

Comment: Not that if you use placement-new you will need to make sure that `self->~Vector3()` gets called at some point. Normal C++ objects have a well-defined lifetime, when you *need* placement-new it's because you're doing something fancy that the language doesn't provide directly.

Answer (score 3):

> Can someone explain why new is being called in this way?

I can tell you what it does. It effectively calls the constructor on an arbitrary piece of memory, thus constructing the object in that piece of memory. Regular `new` both allocates memory and constructs an object in that memory; placement new only does the latter part.

As to why anyone would write that code? No clue. It would make more sense if the object took a `void*` rather than a `Vector3*`. But unless `Vector3::Vector3()` is private, there's no reason to hide the placement new usage inside a static function like this.

Comment: It does NOT  *call the constructor on an **arbitrary** piece of memory*. It *calls the constructor on a **given** piece of memory*.

Comment: @Nawaz That given piece is arbitrary.

Comment: @LucDanton: There is a difference. [Anyone can cook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratatouille_(film)) does not mean that Any Tom-Harry-and-Dick can cook.

Comment: @Nawaz Well, any valid pointer can be given to placement-new, so in your metaphor, Tom-Dick-and-Harry all *can* cook. Luc is right. What Nicol *didn't* say was "calls the constructor on a piece of memory it aritrarily chose", but that's apparently how you read it.

Comment: @spraff: A person who doesn't know what placement-new is, is more likely to interpret the sentence the way I did. Hence, it is misleading. The phrase *"a given piece of memory"* is certainly better and clearer than *"an arbitrary piece of memory"*

Comment: Can we settle on "a given piece of arbitrary memory"? :-P

Answer (score 0):

Real world example: `std::vector` allocates more than enough memory to store its current load, to lower the average cost of a `push_back`.

If it stored a `T*data` buffer then calling `data=new T[capacity]` would default-construct a load of `T` objects. Trouble is, the semantics of `vector` are that it only contains what you've put into it: we may preallocate memory for our objects but **those objects should not exist yet**.

Solution is to make the `vector::data` member a `void*` and allocate untyped memory for it. Now whenever we add an object to the container, we need to construct it in order to bring this object into existence and give meaning to the raw pointer.

```
template <typename T>
void vector <T> :: push_back (const T & value)
{
    resize (m_size + 1);
    // construct a new T in the void buffer.
    new (reinterpret_cast <T*> (m_data) + m_size) T (value);
    ++ m_size;
}

template <typeame T>
void vector <T> :: pop_back ()
{
    (reinterpret_cast <T*> (m_data) + m_size) -> ~ T ();
    -- size;
}
```